# C# ASP.ΝΕΤ MVC many to many find by id, result count = 0, why?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, many-to-many

I'm doing a project for exercises. I need to write a query that will return me a list of tours for the client. Unfortunately, my query returns 0. I searched all the stackoverflows but found nothing. I've been sitting on it for 2 days :-(
This is my class:

```
public class Wycieczka
{
    public Wycieczka()
    {
        this.Klienci = new HashSet<Klient>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int IdWycieczka { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Pole wymagane")]
    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Dlugosc nazwy to maksymalnie 50 znakow")]
    public string nazwa { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> dataWyjazdu { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int iloscOsob { get; set; }

    public virtual Kierowca Kierowca { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Klient> Klienci { get; set; }
}

public class Klient
{
    public Klient()
    {
        this.Wycieczki = new HashSet<Wycieczka>();
    }

    [Key]
    public String pesel { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Pole wymagane")]
    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Dlugosc nazwy to maksymalnie 50 znakow")]
    public string Imie { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Nazwisko { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string adres_email { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Wycieczka> Wycieczki { get; set; }
}
```

and my method in controller:

```
public ViewResult Wycieczki(String pesel)
{
    var wycieczka = (_context.Klient
                             .Where(c => c.pesel == pesel)
                             .Select(c => c.Wycieczki)).ToList();

    return View(wycieczka);
}
```

my View:

```
@model IEnumerable<ApbdProjekt2.Models.Wycieczka>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Lista Wycieczek dla klienta";
}


<div class="container">
    <h2>Lista Wycieczek dla klienta</h2>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Nazwa</th>
            <th>Data Wyjazdu</th>
            <th>ilosc osob</th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var w in Model) 
        {     
            <tr>
                <td>@w.nazwa</td>
                <td>@w.dataWyjazdu</td>
                <td>@w.iloscOsob</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

Please some advice :-)

EDIT:
thank you for help :) i solved my problem. The problem was on my side. In another view, where i get this view i have wrong name of pesel. I have id == pesel. Thank you :-)

Comment: If your result is empty then check your `Where` clause. Chances are that there is no record matching that filter.

Comment: If you check in the database for the `Klient` with the `pesel` value you used, you see results but this results are not retrieved in the method  `Wycieczki`?

Comment: Also, your query returns a `List<ICollection<Wycieczka>>`, but it seems to me that in your view you just want an `IEnumerable<Wycieczka>`. You have to use `SelectMany` and not `Select` if this is the case (this, of course, will show duplicates if any).

Comment: use `.Where(c => c.pesel == pesel).ToList()`

Comment: In database i have 3 table: Klient, Wycieczka and wycieczka_klient. In the Klient is pesel = 76543289876, in the Wycieczka is id_wycieczka = 1 and wycieczka_klient has pesel as fk and id_wycieczka as fk. And pesel and id_wycieczka as the same as klient and wycieczka. As I debugged, I saw the var wycieczka has count = 0

Comment: I wants to display all trips for the customer of the given pesel

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is no database.
Make some examples with created lists created for the database.

Test:

```
public ViewResult Wycieczki(String pesel)
    {
        var _ListKient = new List<Klient> { new Klient { pesel = "AA" }, new Klient { pesel = "BB" }, new Klient { pesel = "CC" }, new Klient { pesel = "DD" } };

        var wycieczka = (_ListKient.Klient).Where(c => c.pesel == pesel).Select(c => c.Wycieczki)).ToList();

        return View(wycieczka);

    }
```

Just an example to see if it is returned.

I hope I have helped you